# Display array values when button/link is clicked (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays as such:

```
   Office:    Array([0]=>1001 [1]=>1002 [2]=>1003 [3]=>1004)

   Canteen:    Array([0]=>2001 [1]=>2002 [2]=>2003)
```

I am trying to display the array in a table like below:

| Location | Users |
| --- | --- |
| Office | 4 |
| Canteen | 3 |

The user column is supposed to display the total count in the array. I am able to do that, however I am also trying to display the array values when the number (user column) is clicked. I need help on that.

User_model.php

```
function get_user_count($location){
$this->db->select('user_id');
$this->db->from('time_location');
$this->db->where('location',$location);
$this->db->where('ack',1);
return query = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

controller.php

```
$status = $this->User_model->get_user_count($location);
if($status){
  $object_id =array_column($status, 'user_id');
  $this->table->add_row($location, $object_id);
} else{
  $object_id = 0;
   $this->table->add_row($location, $object_id);
}
```

So far I am able to display the total user count. How to make the count value as a link/button where if clicked, it will display the user_id array?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, it only runs when you submit a form. If you want to do this without submitting a form, you have to do it in JavaScript. It can use AJAX to get the data from PHP.

Comment: Your link or form needs to pass the location as a parameter, so that you know which array to display data from when you receive that request.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$Office = array(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004);
$Canteen = array(2001, 2002, 2003);
?>
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Users</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Office</td>
        <td>
            <span id="office_count" style="display: block" onclick="myFunction('office_count','office_sum')"><?=count($Office)?></span>
            <span id="office_sum" style="display: none" onclick="myFunction('office_count','office_sum')"><?=array_sum($Office)?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Canteen</td>
        <td>
            <span id="canteen_count" style="display: block" onclick="myFunction('canteen_count','canteen_sum')"><?= count($Canteen)?></span>
            <span id="canteen_sum" style="display: none" onclick="myFunction('canteen_count','canteen_sum')"><?= array_sum($Canteen)?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function myFunction(count, sum) {
        let x = document.getElementById(count);
        let y = document.getElementById(sum);

        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
            y.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            y.style.display = "none";
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Try this!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).